# how to post multiple values to PHP function using AJAX?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have this code:

```
    var name= "theName";
    var surname= $('#surname').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'SaveEdit.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { "callFunc1": whichOne},
        success: function(response) { 
        alert(response);
        }
    });
```

It's working, but i need to do something like this:

```
    var name= "theName";
    var surname= $('#surname').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'SaveEdit.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { "callFunc1": whichOne, name},
        success: function(response) { 
        alert(response);
        }
    });
```

It gives me errors like:
Warning: missing argument 2 for func1()

I am using this code too:

```
function func1($data, $name){
    //some code here
}    

if (isset($_POST['callFunc1'])) {
    echo func1($_POST['callFunc1']);
}
```

How to do it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either create an array and pass as much as variable you want. otherwise try this:-

```
 var name= "theName";
    var surname= $('#surname').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'SaveEdit.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { "callFunc1": whichOne,"callFunc2": name},
        success: function(response) { 
        alert(response);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think it will call Func1 and Func2, but i will try

Comment: i just gave you an example. you can do it as you want.

Comment: Yes array is much better option. it's fast and safe and unlimited variable and values can pass through it also.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a name to your secund parameter in the AJAX call. Don't forgot to pass it ot your function "func1".

Example:

```
if (isset($_POST['callFunc1'])) {
   echo func1($_POST['callFunc1'], $_POST['callFunc2']);
}
```